# Shared Preference Directory - genymotion

Tags: android, directory, sharedpreferences, genymotion

I work on a application that save data on shared preferences
when I using AVD for test my app shared preference file exist in below directory and all things is ok

> /data/data/MY_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/setting.xml

But when I use Genymotion, data folder is empty in eclipse file explorer.
How could I access to shared preferences?

Comment: We fixed this problem several months ago. Can you give me your current genymotion and android device version?

Comment: genymotion : 2.3.0 & android api 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find my answer [here](http://www.programering.com/a/MDM5MTMwATY.html).
this problem Happens when we have not appropriate permissions